# Fetch Count of existence of substring from Cell Values in CSV file - Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

am having a CSV file with a column name MFileName with values

```
1500_MM_19876_USA_TEST_TRXE
1800_RR_12960_US1_TEST_TRAX
1501_MM_19876_US1_TEST_TRXE
1802_RR_12960_USA_TEST_TRAX
1501_MM_19876_US1_TEST_TRXE
1803_RR_12960_USA_TEST_TRAX
1804_RR_12960_US1_TEST_TRAX
```

so, my requirement is show in a slicer, that, the USA ==== 3 &&
 US1 ==== 4

i loaded this csv file into powerbi desktop and wanting to create a report/slicer . 
Am stuck at what DAX query need to be applied in order to get :
 want to fetch 
 1) how many records exist having "USA" as substring
 2) how many records exist having "US1" as substring

I tried with some DAX queryies but its failed.i created a  new column from the power query editor and tried to wrote the query.

```
USAcountcoulmn=IF(FIND("USA",table1(MfILENAME),1,0) >=1,1,0)
```

now i tried with another query :

```
USACountctual = SEARCH("USA",Table1[MFILENAME],,0)
```

as a result it returns , 0 or 1 in the cell values.
 But , how can i get the total number of cells which is having a substring(text) "USA" present in the column "MFILENAME" ?
 in the slicer, i should get the value as 3 for "USA" and 4 for "US1"

Answer (score 1):

Try this measure

```
USACountctual = 
    COUNTAX(
        Table1 ;
        IFERROR( SEARCH( "US1" ; Table1[MFILENAME] ) ; BLANK() )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share the Power Query approach that I believe is just easier in this case.

Create a new column, you can even use "Column for examples" to easily generate the **M** for you.

[image: New Column]

This way you can even use the new column, rename it as you will, and use it as category in your report.

EDIT:

In your report just drag any of the 2 columns and set it as a COUNT, since both columns are TEXT that should already be the default summarization if I'm not mistaken or create a new measure.

```
File Count = COUNTROWS('Table 1')
```

Comment: your query will give us the names usa, us1,  burt how to get the total count of USAs and US1s  present in this csv file ?